# Real-time collaborative HTML source code editor, with real-time preview

Tags: ide, html, html-editor, collaboration

I want my team to collaboratively edit an HTML page.

Imperative requirements:

- Everyone must see other people's changes in real-time (like Google Docs). It makes it so much easier to avoid conflicts.
- Preview must show the current page, in real-time, (IFrame or separate page, best if both are possible)
- Must work with [pages like this](http://nicolas-raoul.github.io/WebCMIS/index.html) (CSS, JQuery performing authentication *(admin/admin in the example)*, AJAX)

[Cloud9](https://c9.io/) is very close to providing this, but, unfortunately, a user's changes are not sent to the other until xe presses "Save", which is a major inconvenience and a constant source of conflicts.

Software or web app. Ideally, Open Source with commercial support and web app free for Open Source projects and limited trials. Non-open source and non-free is OK too.

Comment: Doesn't show HTML preview, but you could modify http://etherpad.org to include that functionality, if no complete solution is found.

Comment: @Olli yes I have thought about that, but I am still hoping someone has done it already, and SR is the perfect place to ask :-)

Comment: Here are [20 of real-time code editors to choose from](https://iprodev.com/20-best-code-editors-for-real-time-collaboration/)

Comment: @niutech: None of them seem to satisfy requirements 2 and 3 of my question. If they actually do, feel free to post an answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's a web app, but you could try [Koding.com](https://koding.com/). It gives you your own "VM" on the web with about 4GB of space to start with. You can import git repositories or .zip files and supports several other platforms too.

It does do real-time collaboration, which works relatively well, although not quite up to par with Google Docs.

Here is a look at it's main editing page:

[image: Koding.com main editing page UI]

I haven't used it much yet myself, but I'm looking at moving some my collaboration stuff to it. Koding also has a "social network" like a section where you can talk with the public or your team/followers.

This isn't the best for a commercial setting, but I think it works well for other things.

Comment: Webapps are OK! Looks good, need to investigate more about its real-time collaboration capabilities, as Google Docs-like collaboration is an imperative requirement.

Comment: Does it have an HTML live preview? See requirements 2 and 3 of my question.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul According to their [features page](https://www.koding.com/features) it does have a built in preview. It does not say whether it is automatic, but I suspect it is.

Comment: Cool! It says "instantly". Now the last thing to check is point 3.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I can't check personally, but it's a full blown VM, it should work just fine.