# HTML editor with real-time preview for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, html-editor, live-preview

I'm looking for an HTML editor which shows real-time previews (including CSS but not JS). I'd like to only edit the code "by hand" (not looking for a WYSIWYG editor).

My OS is Ubuntu GNU/Linux. (I prefer FOSS if possible.)

Related:

- [Real-time collaborative HTML source code editor, with real-time preview](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/272/real-time-collaborative-html-source-code-editor-with-real-time-preview)
- [WYSIWYG HTML editor for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/287/wysiwyg-html-editor-for-linux)

Comment: Here are some Emacs-based approaches: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/476

Answer (score 4):

## WebStorm

[*WebStorm*](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is a very serious tool for web authoring and development. It comes from a company specializing in a family of powerful [IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for professional programmers.

[WebStorm runs on Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=linux) as well as macOS and Windows. A commercial tool, reasonably priced with active development and support.

WebStorm is able to [display live updates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/coding-assistance.html) as you edit a page for instant display rendered in Chrome browser.

> **Live edit**
>
> Live Edit allows you to see page content updates in the browser (Google Chrome only) immediately, without reloading, with the changes you make in your HTML and CSS files. It works as part of the JavaScript debug session.

Answer (score 2):

### Brackets

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is made by Adobe and it's under the MIT license ([github](https://github.com/adobe/brackets)). It has some neat features including live preview and inline CSS editing.

You can install it from a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Comment: for linux mint use "sudo snap install brackets --classic"

Answer (score 1):

The Atom editor is very good for programming in HTML and CSS. There are several plugin packages to turn Atom into more of an IDE than just an editor. It supports real time preview. I've used Atom extensively for both Python and HTML. Atom is free as are the plugins.

Comment: This is not an answer. We all know that there might be a plugin for this and there is for sure a mode for Emacs. Without names it takes as much time then googling atom+html+live+preview

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo snap install brackets --classic
```

works for Ubuntu too and you don't need to add a repository.